# Import Error Can't import Requests on Idle, but can on Jupyter/spider

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

For whatever reason when I try to import requests on idle/shell I get this error message : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'.
I have installed it with pip and I still get an error.
It works 100 percent of the time on Jupyter notebook for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the requests module. pip is the easiest option, but that is not a Python command. First Find the directory where Python installed. Make sure you open CMD "Run as Admin", and run the following commands: for example

```
C:\Python27\Scripts\pip install requests
```